# Making a bar chart with object returned by pd.groupby.sum()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, type-conversion

I am trying to take a pandas dataframe (created by doing a groupby partnerid) that looks like this: (Only with many more rows)

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      partnerid      |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          6          |      25153       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          9          |      13370       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         75          |       47         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And want to make a bar chart.

Normally I would use

```
df['partnerid'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()
```

But I get the error

```
KeyError: 'partnerid'
```

Alternatively I could use Matplotlib, but I do not know how to reference the unnamed column and when renaming it the code runs but does not change the column name.

I think that it might be me trying to do illegal things with the datatype that I am using.

Could someone please help me understand the datatype that comes from a df.groupby.sum() and how I can change it into something that can be turned into a bar chart?

Thanks

Comment: `'partnerid'` is likely your index and not a column if you used `groupby` on `'partnerid'`. That's why you get the `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is what you do in the first step,

```
df = df_initial.groupby(['partnerid']).sum()
```

then, it looks like your df is a pd.Series object, hence you can plot using the following command

```
df.value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question though, how would this change if there was a second index? such as a partition by date for each partnerid